# Recurring event every Sunday of the year

Tags: fullcalendar

How can I make an event recurring every Sunday of the year without having to create an event for every Sunday.

Comment: There's a really good solution using a callback to create an even source [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072616/fullcalendar-jquery-repeat-every-monday).

Answer (score 1):

In basic method from fullcalendar:

You have to create an event at Sunday and repeat each week (not desired):

```
            {
                id: 999,
                title: 'Repeating Event',
                start: new Date(y, m, d+7, 16, 0), // "d" must be start on sunday and be incremented by 7 each event
                allDay: false
            },
```

In advanced method from fullcalendar:

You have to create your own calendar feed dynamically, and then create a recurring event:

```
<entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'
    xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'>
  <category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind'
    term='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#event'></category>
  <title type='text'>Tuesday Tennis Lessons with Jane</title>
  <content type='text'>Meet on Tuesdays for a quick lesson.</content>
  <gd:transparency
    value='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#event.opaque'>
  </gd:transparency>
  <gd:eventStatus
    value='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#event.confirmed'>
  </gd:eventStatus>
  <gd:where valueString='Rolling Lawn Courts'></gd:where>
  <gd:recurrence>DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20100505
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20100506
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=Tu;UNTIL=20100904
</gd:recurrence>
</entry>
```

Code was extracted from http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#CreatingRecurring

Comment: That worked... but it only display once... does got to all Sundays of the year...