# calendar repeat event weekly

Tags: javascript, jquery

does anyone know of a jquery plugin that tell you how many times to repeat an event based on the started and ended date?

I was trying to calculate it myslef, but so far luck :(

```
var cur_dayofweek = calEvent.start.getDay(),
    org_start_date = calEvent.start.getDate(),
    org_end_date = $( '.j-date' ).datepicker( "getDate" ).getDate(), 
    recurring = Math.round(org_end_date/org_start_date);
```

***recurring is wrong.***

Any idea of how can i get this to work or any useful plugin that i can use for it?

NOTE: I'm using jquery-week-calendar plugin

Comment: are you trying to repeat the event daily, weekly, or what?

Comment: I'm trying to do a repeat weekly

Comment: now I see you wrote that in the title.  duh.

Comment: not familiar with jquery-week-calendar plugin; does that easily convert to JS Date objects if I were going to write a function based on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function works, where startDate and endDate are JS Date objects. http://jsfiddle.net/n43Hr/

```
var getWeeklyEventCount = function (startDate, endDate) {
    var secondOccurrence = new Date(startDate.getFullYear(), startDate.getMonth(), startDate.getDate()+7);
    if (endDate.getTime() >= secondOccurrence.getTime()) {
        return 1 + getWeeklyEventCount(secondOccurrence, endDate);
    }
    if (endDate.getTime() >= startDate.getTime()) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
};
```

Comment: sure - it was kind of fun to think about it.

Answer (score 0):

There is plugin called jQuery Fullcalender

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

which by default doesn't support this feature but you can go to below links which will help you to achieve the same

[fullCalendar jQuery, repeat every monday?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072616/fullcalendar-jquery-repeat-every-monday)

https://coderwall.com/p/rti-rg

Comment: unfortunately we are using `jquery-week-calendar` plugin

Comment: ohh actually u didn't mention that in your question.

Comment: um, my bad - just added

Comment: please refer to following link http://jdarwood.com/2011/12/jquery-week-calendar-reoccurring-events/