# Recurring Timed Events in FullCalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar and Date.js to set up a weekly agenda. I'm also using the answer from [fullCalendar jQuery, repeat every monday?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072616/fullcalendar-jquery-repeat-every-monday) for recurring events - but I'm struggling to convert these events to a specific time, rather than all day.

```
var date = new Date();
var d = date.getDate();
var m = date.getMonth();
var y = date.getFullYear();

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek'
});

// adding a every monday and wednesday events:
$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'addEventSource',        
    function(start, end, callback) {
        // When requested, dynamically generate virtual
        // events for every monday and wednesday.
        var events = [];

        for (loop = start.getTime();
             loop <= end.getTime();
             loop = loop + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) {

            var test_date = new Date(loop);

            if (test_date.is().monday()) {
                events.push({
                    title: 'Meeting',
                    start: test_date
                });
            }
        } // for loop

        // return events generated
        callback( events );
    }
);
```

I've tried changing the "if" to check for time as well with no luck and I've tried setting the time of the test_date variable, without success.

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, sulaiman, that was helpful. I also had to toss out date.js - it's no longer in development and many features are broken. Here's the full solution I reached.

```
var date = new Date();
var d = date.getDate();
var m = date.getMonth();
var y = date.getFullYear();

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    defaultEventMinutes: 45,
    editable: false
});

$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'addEventSource',        
    function(start, end, callback) {
        // When requested, dynamically generate virtual events for every monday and wednesday.
        var events = [];

        // checks every 30 minutes, rather than 24 hours
        for (loop = start.getTime(); loop <= end.getTime(); loop = loop + (30 * 60 * 1000)) {

            var test_date = new Date(loop);

            if (test_date.getDay() === 1 && test_date.getHours() === 11 && test_date.getMinutes() === 30){
                events.push({
                    title: 'Meeting',
                    start: test_date
                    allDay: false
                });
            }
        } // for loop

        // return events generated
        callback( events );
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `allDay: false`

```
if (test_date.is().monday()) {
    events.push({
     title: 'Meeting',
     start: test_date,
     allDay: false
   });
}
```