# Full calendar repeat event every two days

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Is it possible to repeat specific event every two or three days in Full Calendar?

For example I want to see on my calendar "Reunion" every two days from the start date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the dow property on the event like this:

```
events: [{
  title:"My repeating event",
  start: '10:00', // a start time (10am in this example)
  end: '14:00', // an end time (6pm in this example)
  //Days of week. an array of zero-based day of week integers (0=Sunday)
  dow: [ 1, 4 ] // Repeat monday and thursday
}],
```

slicedToad's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29393128/3891834) explains this fully.

Alternatively you could use a function like in Christopher Ramírez's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11111784/3891834).

In the application I am currently working on we are generating repeating events but are doing it server side before passing them to the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they would need to be created as separate events which have the same event id. There is no other support for recurring events in fullCalendar. You can do it programmatically, e.g. if your event has a certain flag defined by you, e.g. flag: "REPEAT2", then your script would create several other events say for the next 1 month that would have the same id, but different dates.